# Asymptotic Analysis of Sum

Tags: asymptotics

I want to do an analysis on the sum $ \Sigma_{i=0}^n  f(i)$. All that is known about $f(i)$ is that $f(i) \in \Theta (i \log i ) $.

How do I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: Hint: Unfold the definition of "$f \in \Theta(\dots)$". You will have to do two proofs/calculations for bounds on the sum. Be careful about making $n_0$ large enough.

Comment: @Raphael I believe there's a quicker solution based on Stirling here.

Comment: Approximate the sum by an integral.